# VBA Data Validation Listbox IF formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column (C) in a worksheet that lists country using a listbox in the Data Validation option. I have the next column (D) which has State.

I could create one list of state types but I was wondering if there is a way in the frontend of Excel of in VBA to make the following:

- Where Column C Country = "USA" then column D list States
- Where Column C Country = "Canada" then column D list Province

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ordered lists (in your case by country name) can feed a dependent dropdown see [link](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html). I would use pivots as intermediary to reduce redundancy. No need for VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the country options in column **G**; put the USA options in column **E**; put the Canado options in column **F**:

[image]

Then in column **C**, setup *DV* using column **G**.  In **D2**, for example, enter *DV* with the **List** option and the *formula:*

```
=IF(C2="USA",E1:E11,F1:F11)
```

[image]

After this, the displayed options in **D2** will adapt to the value selected in **C2**.